# syntax highlighting to factory default in texstudio in mac os x

Tags: texstudio

How to reset

```
syntax highlighting
```

to factory default in texstudio in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings for syntax highlighting are stored in the [settings file](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored). Section `[formats]` contains all changes done by the user. If a format is not listed there, its default will be used. So you can just delete all entries. Note: TXS has to be closed before editing texstudio.ini, otherwise the changes will not take effect and will be overwritten when you close TXS.